# How to update state in a fcm handler with StateNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

In my Flutter app i need being able to react on incoming fcm messages which can instruct the app to go a different navigation tab by having a corresponding key/value pair in its data payload.
Currently the selected index is stored in the stateful widget which also hosts the bottom navigation bar:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    presentTicketsModel = ref.watch(presentTicketsModelProvider);
    contractsModel = ref.watch(contractsModelProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: PersistentTabs(
        currentTabIndex: index,
        screenWidgets: buildPages(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        height: 60,
        selectedIndex: index,
        onDestinationSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          this.index = index;
        }),
        destinations: _buildNavigationDestinations(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

With the new challenge i thought about moving that state index into a separate object and use Riverpod's StateNotifierProvider to provide that state object, as it is described in the official doc (https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider).

What i don't get is: How can the following service class (which listens for incoming fcm messages) get hold of that state object and update the index in order that the watching view class gets notified and can switch to the targeted navigation tab?

```dart
class PushNotificationService {
  final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialise() async {
    print('initialising push notification service...');
    }

    /// foreground handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      // here the state change would be done
    });

    /// handler if the app has been opened from a background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessageOpenedApp: $message');
    });

  }
}
```

Or asked differently: How does this service class get passed a ProviderReference in order to access the mentioned state object and change the index value?

The service currently is registered with GetIt as a lazy singleton:

```dart
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(PushNotificationService.new);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `initialise` method can have a `Ref` parameter like so:

```
class PushNotificationService {
  final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialise(WidgetRef ref) async {
    print('initialising push notification service...');
    }

    /// foreground handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
     // Use ref.read here -> ref.read();
    });

    /// handler if the app has been opened from a background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessageOpenedApp: $message');
    });

  }
}
```

Then you can pass a ref when calling initialise.

```
PushNotificationService.initialise(ref);
```

> If you'd be calling `initialise` in a widget, use `WidgetRef` instead of `Ref`

#### EDIT: ***Where to pass ref (notice that we're using `WidgetRef` now)***

##### Follow these steps

- Make `MyApp` a `ConsumerStatefulWidget`
- Call `PushNotificationService.initialise(ref);`  in `initState`

##### Full code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {

  @override
  initState(){
   PushNotificationService.initialise(ref);
   super.initState();
  }
  
class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Passing in ref is not a problem, the question is: Where do i get this ref param from? Meanwhile someone else proposed to create another provider for this service class (which then will get a ProviderReference as param). On app startup i would need to start a listener for this provider (without actually using it), but it should work then.

Comment: Hi @valley, I've made an edit to my answer, please check it.

Comment: Hi @Josteve, thanks again for your efforts. Like that it would be indeed easy. The problem is that this class has to be initialized on app startup, i.e. in main(), where i definitely don't have an XYRef available. As mentioned i will try to create a StateNotifierProvider for this class and listen to it in main(). Like that i can pass a ProviderReference into the class and therefore can access the state object which i need to update on incoming FCM messages.

Comment: The initState would somewhat be called on app start up. which should in turn call that method...If you make it a StateNotifierProvider, you'd still need a ref to listen to it right?

Comment: Hmmm, yes, that's right indeed. So you mean the initState of the very first widget (App) which is called in main by runApp(), from where i could pass the WidgetRef object into the initialise method?

Comment: Yes, something on that line

Comment: Ok, i will try it tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i got it working today with a similar approach you suggested above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @valley did it works for you?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Yes, i does work now fine.

Comment: how did you handle it?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Passing ref.read when defining the provider: `final pushNotificationHandlerProvider =
  Provider((ref) => PushNotificationHandler(ref.read));`